# Выделяет красным строки с v-for в Vue.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js

По какой то причине у меня постоянно выделяется красным строчки

```
 <option v-for="user in users" v-bind:value="users">{{user.name}}</option>
```

и

```
<li v-for="user in selectedUsers">{{user.name}}</li>
```

Общий вид кода:

```html
    <template>
    <div class = "ryte">
        <label><b><h2>Атрибуты формы</h2></b></label>
    <label>
    Введите фамилию*:
    <input type = "text" v-model = "lastname" placeholder = "Например, Петров"/>
    </label>
<br>
<br>
    <label>
    Введите имя*:
    <input type = "text" v-model = "firstname" placeholder = "Например, Иван"/>
    </label>
<br>
<br>
    <label>
    Введите отчество:
    <input type = "text" v-model = "lastname" placeholder = "Например, Васильевич"/>
    </label>
<br>
<br>
    <label>
    Введите дату рождения*:
    <input type = "date" v-model = "date" class="form-control"/>
    </label>
<br>
<br>
    <label>
    Введите номер телефона*:
    <input type = "phone"  value = "+7(   )"  maxlength = "16" />
    </label>
<br>
<br>
    <label>
    Пол:
    <input type = "text"  placeholder = "Например,Женский" v-model = "text"/>
    </label>
<br>
<br>
<div class = "app">
    Группа клиентов:
     <select v-model="selectedUsers" multiple>
          <option v-for="user in users" v-bind:value="users">{{user.name}}</option>
     </select>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="user in selectedUsers">{{user.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  
    </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script>
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        users: [
            {name: 'VIP'},
            {name: 'Проблемные'},
            {name: 'ОМС'}
        ],
        selectedUsers:[]
    }
});
</script>
```

Версия Vue.js у меня стоит 4
Не пойму, что ему надо((

Answer (score 0):

[Вот тут](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) можно почитать об этом. [И вот тут](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key). Проще говоря, всегда используй атрибут `key` при отрисовке списков.

```html
<option v-for="(user, index) of users" :key="index" :value="users">{{user.name}}</option>
```

Comment: Да, теперь работает)Правда в скрипте показывает ошибку "16:5   error  'app' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
  16:15  error  'Vue' is not defined                      no-undef"